# When I add autolayout, the views disapear

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have 1 `label` and 1 `UICollectionView` in an overall `view`. I'm trying to get them like the image below:

[image]

I can't use the storyboard to apply auto-layout, I have to do it programmatically, and I'm having difficulty doing that. Here is what I have:

```
CGRect collectionViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height - 20);
_datesCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:collectionViewFrame collectionViewLayout:collectionViewLayout];

_labelToChange = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 20)];

[_labelToChange setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[datesCollectionView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[_labelToChange]-[_datesCollectionView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelToChange, _datesCollectionView)]];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_labelToChange]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelToChange)]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_labelToChange]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelToChange)]];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_datesCollectionView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_datesCollectionView)]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_datesCollectionView]|"options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_datesCollectionView)]];
```

When I run it on the simulator, I don't see any of the view's, and I get the following error:

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa080d801b0 H:|-(0)-[DIDatepicker:0x7fa080d7f9a0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa080d7f360 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa080d80250 H:[DIDatepicker:0x7fa080d7f9a0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa080d7f360 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa080da9120 H:[UILabel:0x7fa080da8350]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7fa081159000]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa080daa7e0 H:[UILabel:0x7fa080da8350]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7fa080d7f9a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa080daab50 H:|-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7fa081159000]   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7fa080d7f9a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa080db70c0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa080d7f360(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa080da9120 H:[UILabel:0x7fa080da8350]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7fa081159000]>
```

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: DId you solve your problem

Comment: Yes. Thanks!! Both answers solve my problem

Comment: I suggest you to implement from story board or nib file. It will be hard in beginning but latter it will make you much easier

Comment: Thanks!! I would have done that, but I have custom views I implemented. But thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is ambigious:

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[_labelToChange]-[_datesCollectionView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelToChange, _datesCollectionView)]];
```

And you don't have any width or height information defined for the views. AutoLayout doesn't have enough information to layout your view.

Try this instead:

```
NSDictionary *dict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelToChange, _datesCollectionView);

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[_labelToChange(80)]-0-[_datesCollectionView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_labelToChange]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_datesCollectionView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];
```

What I've done here is, I have defined the label to be 80 pixels tall and the collectionview then takes the rest of the height of the superview.

Comment: Thanks for answering!! I created their frames, but I just didn't post it. I updated the question with the frames.

Comment: Frames are ignored in AutoLayout. The width and height of the views are defined by the constraints instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your constraint :

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[_labelToChange]-[_datesCollectionView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelToChange, _datesCollectionView)]];
```

is conflicting with constraints :

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_labelToChange]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelToChange)]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_datesCollectionView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_datesCollectionView)]];
```

You need to replace the constraints as shown below :

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[_labelToChange(20)]-0-[_datesCollectionView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_labelToChange]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelToChange)]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_datesCollectionView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_datesCollectionView)]];
```

Hope it helps.. :)